# Sparkline clickdemo barchart

Tags: jquery, sparklines

I would like to use the sparklineClick Event for sparkline barcharts.

It seems that this only works for line charts. When I use the code from the demo I get `undefined` for the region.

```
    $('.clickdemo').sparkline('html', {type: 'bar', barColor: 'red'});
    $('.clickdemo').bind('sparklineClick', function(ev) {
        var sparkline = ev.sparklines[0],
            region = sparkline.getCurrentRegionFields();
        alert('Clicked on x=' + region.x + ' y=' + region.y);
    });
```

Does somebody know a workaround to get to get back at least a correct x value?

Answer (score 1):

the code forrowing might be helpful:

```
$('#chart1').bind('sparklineClick', function(ev){
  var sparkline = ev.sparklines[0],
  region = sparkline.getCurrentRegionFields();
  console.log(region[0]);
  alert('Clicked on x=' + region[0].offset + ' y=' + region[0].value);
})
```